# CSS Non-Related Selector

Tags: html, css

In CSS I am trying to select a non-related (not the elements parent or child) when an action like a hover or checked occurs.

This is the code I have working (http://codepen.io/danielrowe/pen/jHAur) which shows the basics of what I am trying to do, although it selects the next element.

The issue with that code is that when you change the HTML to have something between `#menu-toggle` and `#menu` as expected the menu will not show.

So is there anyway I can select an element somewhere different on the page using the same basic principle here **without using javascript**?

**Edit**

It appears I simplified my working code a little too much, in my "production" code I have the elements in separate div containers (So menu and content sort of idea) - An example: http://codepen.io/danielrowe/pen/hxGwK

Comment: Generally speaking, without Javascript, no. There are some "hacks" that work using styled check boxes, labels, etc. but they aren't too reliable. Just out of curiosity, why can't you use Javascript? http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: The method I am currently using is a checkbox hack (although uses radios).  I would like to use it just incase a user doesn't have javascript enabled (the content hidden is vital not an improvement to user experience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CSS Target Selector**
>
> URLs with an # followed by an anchor name, link to a certain element
>   within a document. The element being linked to is the target element.

This is the best solution I can think of: http://codepen.io/heyvian/pen/KIGfj

Using the CSS Target selector you could have a link targeting the ID of a menu

```
<a href="#newmenu">NewMenu</a>

<ul class="menu" id="newmenu">
  <li><a href="#">A link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then using CSS you could display it with

```
.menu:target{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I over simplified my code!  In my production code they are in 2 separate `div` containers like [This example](http://codepen.io/danielrowe/pen/hxGwK)

Comment: @Daniel Changed my answer. Updated example too.

Comment: that works almost perfect, the only reason I was using radios / checkboxes was because you can set one to active by default; I can't seem to think of a way to do this with links?

Comment: @Daniel Might be possible if you start adding unnecessary markup using wrapper divs and so forth but this really is what Javascript is meant for. Out of ideas at the moment. If this is a backup for no JS, which is getting rarer and rarer, having a default menu open might not be a deal breaker.

Comment: Good point, so long as those without JS can access the content then JS serves as an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you're looking for is the `~` selector instead of `+`. The `+` selector selects the item directly after while `~` selects any items after.

So instead of:

```
#menu-toggle:checked + #menu
```

You want

```
#menu-toggle:checked ~ #menu
```

[Check out this example,](http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/leLhi) let me know if I misunderstood

Comment: Sorry, I over simplified my code!  In my production code they are in 2 separate `div` containers like [This example](http://codepen.io/danielrowe/pen/hxGwK)

Comment: Yeah, we have to wait until CSS4 to deal with this kind of situation: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Comment: Thanks, as these aren't out yet I'll have to try another work around.  Thanks again for your help though.